# How to use jq to remove a path method (based on a x-* property) from OpenAPI 3.0 or Swagger 2.0 json?

Tags: json, swagger, jq, openapi

I am new to **jq** and this one seems impossible to write. So need some help from jq gurus out there:

So I have an Open API spec file, let's take version 3.0 for example:

The `paths` element has `endpoints` listed, and each of them has methods(`get`, `post`, etc.)

I need a jq filter to select ONLY those methods marked with `"x-visibility": "public"` and leave everything else out.

### So far, I've tried this:

```
.paths |= map(select(.[]."x-visibility" == "public" | not))
```

Obviously, it doesn't work.

### Any help/pointers will be appreciated!

Here is the OpenAPI 3.0 spec file (extra stuff stripped off):

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "API service",
    "description": "Exposing useful methods",
    "x-descriptionForPublicDocs": "This is a test description for public docs specifically",
    "contact": {
      "name": "Message me",
      "url": "https://message.me"
    },
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:9090",
      "description": "Generated server url"
    }
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "AccountGroups"
    }
  ],
  "x-tags": [
    {
      "name": "TestResourceLists"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/crane/v1/resource_list/{id}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "ResourceLists"
        ],
        "x-tags": "TestResourceLists",
        "x-visibility": "public",
        "summary": "Get Resource List by ID",
        "description": "Returns the resource list that has the specified ID.",
        "operationId": "getById",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "ResourceList Id",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json; charset=UTF-8": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ResourceListModel"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "4XX": {
            "description": "Client error",
            "content": {
              "application/json; charset=UTF-8": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SpringErrorResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "put": {
        "tags": [
          "ResourceLists"
        ],
        "x-visibility": "internal",
        "summary": "Update Resource List",
        "description": "Updates the resource list that has the specified ID.",
        "operationId": "update",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "ResourceList Id",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "description": "Model for Resource List",
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ResourceListModel"
              },
              "examples": {
                "TAG": {
                  "description": "Tag ResourceList",
                  "value": {
                    "members": [
                      {
                        "string": "string"
                      }
                    ],
                    "name": "string",
                    "resourceListType": "TAG",
                    "description": "string"
                  }
                },
                "RESOURCE_GROUP": {
                  "description": "RESOURCE_GROUP ResourceList",
                  "value": {
                    "description": "string",
                    "members": [
                      "string",
                      "string"
                    ],
                    "name": "string",
                    "resourceListType": "RESOURCE_GROUP"
                  }
                },
                "COMPUTE_ACCESS_GROUP": {
                  "description": "COMPUTE_ACCESS_GROUP ResourceList",
                  "value": {
                    "description": "string",
                    "members": [
                      {
                        "appIDs": [
                          "*"
                        ],
                        "clusters": [
                          "*"
                        ],
                        "codeRepos": [
                          "*"
                        ],
                        "containers": [
                          "*"
                        ],
                        "functions": [
                          "*"
                        ],
                        "hosts": [
                          "*"
                        ],
                        "images": [
                          "*"
                        ],
                        "labels": [
                          "*"
                        ],
                        "namespaces": [
                          "*"
                        ]
                      }
                    ],
                    "name": "string",
                    "resourceListType": "COMPUTE_ACCESS_GROUP"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "required": true
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json; charset=UTF-8": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ResourceListModel"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "4XX": {
            "description": "Client error",
            "content": {
              "application/json; charset=UTF-8": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SpringErrorResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "tags": [
          "ResourceLists"
        ],
        "x-visibility": "internal",
        "summary": "Delete Resource List",
        "description": "Deletes the resource list that has the specified ID.",
        "operationId": "delete",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "ResourceList Id",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "204": {
            "description": "Successful operation"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "4XX": {
            "description": "Client error",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SpringErrorResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/crane/v1/account_group/{id}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "AccountGroups"
        ],
        "x-visibility": "public",
        "summary": "Get resource",
        "description": "Returns something",
        "operationId": "getById_1",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Account Group ID",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "includeAccountInfo",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "Include Cloud Account details",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AccountGroupModel"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "4XX": {
            "description": "Client error",
            "content": {
              "application/json; charset=UTF-8": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SpringErrorResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
      },
      "put": {
        "tags": [
          "AccountGroups"
        ],
        "x-visibility": "internal",
        "summary": "Update resource",
        "description": "Update information",
        "operationId": "update_1",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "AccountGroup Id",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json; charset=UTF-8": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AccountGroupModel"
              }
            }
          },
          "required": true
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "4XX": {
            "description": "Client error",
            "content": {
              "application/json; charset=UTF-8": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SpringErrorResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "tags": [
          "AccountGroups"
        ],
        "x-visibility": "internal",
        "summary": "Delete resource",
        "description": "Deletes the resource",
        "operationId": "delete_1",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Delete resource",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Internal Server Error",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "4XX": {
            "description": "Client error",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SpringErrorResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `map_values` for objects (`map` is for arrays): `.paths[] |= map_values(select(."x-visibility" == "public"))`

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response! It actually worked! Can't believe it's such a tiny detail. Any idea on how to remove those "dangling" paths that have no methods inside them as a result e.g. `"/crane/v1/account_group/{id}": {}`

Comment: Use `del` to delete fields: `.paths |= del(.[] | select(. == {}))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.paths |= map_values(
   if type == "object"
   then with_entries(select(
        if .value|objects|has("x-visibility") 
        then .value|.["x-visibility"] == "public" 
        else true end) )
   else . end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map_values` to apply a function to all values of an object. You have two nested objects, so you need to call `map_values` twice:

```
.paths |= map_values(map_values(select(."x-visibility" == "public")))
```

To strip empty paths, select only those values which are not an empty array:

```
.paths |= map_values(
    map_values(select(."x-visibility" == "public"))
    | select(. != {})
)
```

or perhaps even one of the following:

```
.paths |= map_values(
    map_values(select(."x-visibility" == "public"))
    | select(length > 0)
)
```

```
.paths |= map_values(
    map_values(select(."x-visibility" == "public"))
    | select(any)
)
```